# Aspose java, Heap size error while binding pdf file

Tags: java, aspose

While binding a pdf file using Aspose i got a heap size error.here is the code
the pdf file is 110MB, and consist of 60000 pages

```
PdfExtractor extractor = new PdfExtractor();
// bind input pDF file
extractor.bindPdf(this.filePath);
```

I increased the java heap size like follow -Xms512M -Xmx1024M but the error persist.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the error comes on bindPdf() method, then there is no way anyone could figure out the issue. Just to make sure that it is heap related issue, try to increase the heap size further and see if it gets loaded with more memory.

Please post in [Aspose.Pdf](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.pdf-product-family/20/showforum.aspx) forums and report this problem.

I am a Developer Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Ok thanks Saqib, i post it in Aspose.Pdf and here is the link http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/471178/aspose-java-heap-size-error-while-binding-pdf-file/showthread.aspx#471178